How to find the canonical form of a second order linear PDE when after substituting back i get something wrong?
I have the problem $u_{xx}-6u_{xy}+9u_{yy}=xy^2$, i can see the discriminant is 0 so that means a parabolic PDE of the form $u_{qq}=f\left(q,r,u_{q},u_{r}\right)$, but when I do all the steps I end up with a different form, here's what I did:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{6\pm\sqrt{0}}{2}=3\Rightarrow y-3x=q$$
checking the substitutions I found are valid:
$$\begin{cases}
q=y-3x\\
r=x
\end{cases}\Rightarrow J=\begin{vmatrix}-3 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{vmatrix}=-1\neq0$$
calculating the partial derivatives:
$$\begin{cases}
u_{x}=u_{q}\cdot q_{x}+u_{r}\cdot r_{x} & =-3u_{q}+u_{r}\\
u_{xx}=\left(-3u_{q}+u_{r}\right)_{x}=-3\cdot u_{qq}\cdot q_{x}-3u_{qr}\cdot r_{x}+u_{rr}\cdot r_{x}+u_{rq}\cdot q_{x} & =9u_{qq}+u_{rr}-6u_{qr}\\
u_{y}=u_{q}\cdot q_{y}+u_{r}\cdot r_{y} & =u_{q}\\
u_{yy}=\left(u_{q}\right)_{y}=u_{qq}\cdot q_{y}+u_{qr}\cdot r_{y} & =u_{qq}\\
u_{xy}=u_{yx}=\left(u_{q}\right)_{x}=u_{qq}\cdot q_{x}+u_{qr}\cdot r_{x} & =-3u_{qq}+u_{qr}
\end{cases}$$
plugging what I found to the original PDE:
$$9u_{qq}+u_{rr}-6u_{qr}-6\left(-3u_{qq}+u_{qr}\right)+9\left(u_{qq}\right)=r\left(q+3r\right)^{2}$$
$$36u_{qq}+u_{rr}-12u_{qr}=r\left(q+3r\right)^{2}$$
where at this point I should have arrived at the canonical form.
(and on a side comment what do I do in general when the jacobian is 0?)

The PDE $u_{xx}-6u_{xy}+9u_{yy}=xy^2$ can be rewritten as
$$
(\partial_x-3\partial_y)^2u=xy^2. \tag{1}
$$
With the change of coordinates $(x,y)\mapsto(q,r)=(x,y+ax)$, we have
\begin{align}
\partial_x&=q_x\partial_q+r_x\partial_r=\partial_q+a\partial_r, \tag{2} \\
\partial_y&=q_y\partial_q+r_y\partial_r=\partial_r. \tag{3}
\end{align}
Rewriting $(1)$ in terms of the new coordinates, we get
$$
[\partial_q+(a-3)\partial_r]^2u=q(r-aq)^2. \tag{4}
$$
Finally, if we choose $a=3$, we obtain
$$
\partial_q^2u=q(r-3q)^2. \tag{5}
$$

I'm not sure I'm following, in the change of coordinates I guess it's an arbitrary decision if q or r gets the x and the other the y-3x, but it seems like we've done two different ways to get to the solution.
we haven't learned this way so even though I think I get it I can't answer this way

The other is $y\color{red}{+}3x$. I suspect your teacher/professor will not be upset if you solve a problem using a method that they didn't teach you. But if you want to know what is the mistake you made using this particular method, you should make this clear in your question.

why is it a plus? according to the first ODE I have in my question it has to be -3.
I understand why in your way it has to be a +3 but as I've said I'm more interested in understanding where my mistake is.
